# JAX-WS Maven and NetBeans

Tags: web-services, netbeans, maven, jax-ws, glassfish-3

I am using netbeans 7 very successfully with JDK6. I need to add a JAX-WS webservice[ws] interface to my application to consume EJB service already created in the app. Since I moved to maven2 I had no issues with deployments on glassfish v3.1 and it seemed to work all fine apart from the new ws.

here is the list of issues I still have:

- WS are not deployed and the WSDL are not generated
- issues with the root context is nt recognised and the test WS is just after the localhost address.
- I cannot configure security constrain for the WS, there is a JACC error and the WS is not available

I used to be able to secure the ws (Ant) with simple web.xml BASIC auth but with maven this is not working any more. I created a test Ant project and everything is working fine.

I think the solution is in the pom.xml (archetype?) where the correct build plug-ins are included?
I am not sure what code to include part from the pom.xml I am using.

`http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        ....`

```
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>at.web.ws</artifactId>
<version>3.4.2</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>at.web.ws Web App</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <id>metro</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[metro]</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

any advise will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question :)

I found this amazing plugin that looks after everything and make sure it is all deployed under the ear project.

http://el4j.sourceforge.net/plugins/index.html

I hope this will help someone
Cheers,
G.